# How to .push into an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, promise

Reading 3 sets of files recursively by date to load into one array of arrays of objects to send to a graphing function

This worked previously when I didn't have a promise all and I was just pushing into one spot of Loaded_Data:

i.e.:

```
Loaded_Data = [];

 d3.tsv("location.txt").then( { data => data.forEach( d => {Loaded_data.push(d);}) } );
```

works fine.

When I try to change "Loaded_Data=[];" to:

```
Loaded_Data = [[],[],[]];  //empty the array from previous load

Promise.all([d3.tsv("location.txt"), d3.tsv("location2.txt"), d3.tsv("location3.txt")])
.then( data => {
    data[0].forEach( d =>  { Loaded_Data[0].push(d);})
    data[1].forEach( d =>  { Loaded_Data[1].push(d);})
    data[2].forEach( d =>  { Loaded_Data[2].push(d);})
});
```

when i console.log(Loaded_Data) i expect:

```
[[{object1a},{o2a},{o3a},{...}],[{object1b},{o2b},o3b},{...}],[{object1c},{o2c},{o3c}]]
```

But I get the error: "Loaded_Data[0].push(d) is not a function"

Isn't this the correct way to access my array of arrays of objects?

Comment: Is this your actual code? You've initialized the `Loaded_Data` array with three inner arrays, so you should not be getting that error with the current code posted here.

Comment: Show the actual code block....

Comment: Try adding `console.log(typeof Loaded_data[0]);` somewhere to debug

Comment: @djfdev This is my actual code with paths hidden

Comment: @epascarello  This is my actual code with paths hidden

Comment: OK. What do you get when you run `console.log(Loaded_Data)` at the beginning of the `then` callback function?

Comment: @Asleepace Typeof is object for somereason? running that right after my array init

Comment: @HAZRD that's correct array will return object, what does it show if you just `console.log(Loaded_Data[0]);`

Comment: @HAZRD also run it inside the callback of the then statement

Comment: Do `var myVariable = [];` rather than `myVariable = [];` otherwise you are using global scope and who knows what it will be then!

Comment: @Asleepace I cant get my code to get inside the .then().  My console errors out before it logs anything

Comment: @HAZRD add a `.catch(error => console.log(error))` after the then (before the semicolon), it may be another issue

Comment: @tic adding var to my array declaration causes my code to just pass through?? no errors not console.log

Answer (score -2):

Looks like dumb me going from one instance to the recursive forgot to include an iterator and i was getting essentially a ... wait for it ... STACK OVERFLOW!!! .

I was explaining my code to my rubber ducky and found it. what a waste of 2 hours.
*facepalm*